# When to use s3cmd over accessing the S3 API programmatically?

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd

I've been having difficulty understanding when to use s3cmd program over using the Java API. A vendor has documentation on accessing S3 with s3cmd. It is unclear to me as the bucket names appear to be dynamic. No region is specified. Additionally, I'm reaching out over an endpoint. I've tried writing some Java code to interact with S3 the same way that s3cmd does but I haven't been able to connect. Overall, it appears to quite a bit different.

To me s3cmd seems to be a utility to manipulate these files or quickly get at them. Integrating this utility into a Java program seems meaningless.

Anyone have any resources or can help me understand this better?

Answer (score 0):

S3cmd (s3cmd) is a free command line tool and client for uploading, retrieving and managing data in Amazon S3 and other cloud storage service providers that use the S3 protocol, such as Google Cloud Storage or DreamHost DreamObjects. It is best suited for power users who are familiar with command line programs. It is also ideal for batch scripts and automated backup to S3, triggered from cron, etc.

S3cmd is written in Python. It's an open source project available under GNU Public License v2 (GPLv2) and is free for both commercial and private use. You will only have to pay Amazon for using their storage.

Lots of features and options have been added to S3cmd, since its very first release in 2008.... we recently counted more than 60 command line options, including multipart uploads, encryption, incremental backup, s3 sync, ACL and Metadata management, S3 bucket size, bucket policies, and more!